# How can I get my UISwitch to do something?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiswitch, theos

How can I get my UISwitch to call this function: https://ghostbin.com/paste/y2xrc when turned on, and return FALSE; when it is turned off.

(I got the switch to show inside "CKTranscriptCollectionViewController" in the Messages.app (MobileSMS.app), and now I want it to do something when turned on or off which is what I posted in the link above).

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ChatKit/CKConversation.h>

@interface CKTranscriptCollectionViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISwitch *mySwitch;
- (void)loadView;
@end

%hook CKTranscriptCollectionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    %orig;
    UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 51, 31)];
    [mySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:mySwitch];
}

%end
```

Answer (score 1):

define a bool in your header file,

```
BOOL allowForceMMS;

-(BOOL)forceMMS {
    return allowForceMMS;
)

- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    %orig;
    UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 51, 31)];

    //add action on switch to handle switch on/off
    [mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(setState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [mySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:mySwitch];
}

-(void)setState:(UISwitch*)switch {
    allowForceMMS = switch.isOn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChangeHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 0):

do this in your viewdidload

```
[switchTemp addTarget:self action:@selector(ChangeValue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and this func

```
-(BOOL)forceMMS
{
     if (switchTemp.isOn)
     { 
       return YES;
     }
     else
     {
    return NO;
     }
 }
```

Comment: But how would I do this to call the function I posted in the link above, -(BOOL)forceMMS?

Comment: do want it to be called by switch or yourself

Comment: @BrandonSalgado i changed it to your funcs name ... and this will be called by switch when tapped and you can call this manually by [self forceMMS] and save BOOL value.

Answer (score 0):

You can give target to be called..when switch is changed..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   

UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 51, 31)];
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[mySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:mySwitch];
}
-(void)valueChange:(UISwitch*)switch
{
if(switch.isOn)
{
     //switch is on
}
else
{
     //switch is off
}

}
```

Hope it helps you..!

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a UISwitch as below in viewDidLoad method,

```
UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChangeHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then in method call in case of switch change, check for state "ON" (bool value is YES or n=NO)

```
-(void)switchValueChangeHandler:(UISwitch*)sender
{
  NSLog(@"%@",sender.on);
}
```

Then according to sender.on is true or false you could perform your operation.